# azure devops pipeline | bash script to run dotnet test on multiple projects

Tags: bash, .net-core, azure-devops

I'm trying to run the `dotnet test` command on defined test projects in a MS Azure devops pipeline.

This is working:

```sh
- script: |
    dotnet test "./Project One/Project One Unit Tests.fsproj" -c Release --no-build --filter "TestCategory!=SKIP_ON_DEPLOY & TestCategory!=REQUIRES_API_KEY"
    dotnet test "./Project Two/Project Two Unit Tests.fsproj" -c Release --no-build --filter "TestCategory!=SKIP_ON_DEPLOY & TestCategory!=REQUIRES_API_KEY"
  displayName: 'run tests in cascade'
```

I don't want to specify the project names, only some rule (project name has to end with "UnitTests", "Unit Tests" or "Unit_Tests") but `dotnet test <PROJECT>` does not allows wildcards.
Seems like wildcards works with `dotnet test <DLL>` (./**/*Unit?Tests.dll) but it fails because it does not find the *deps.json* file on the obj folder.

My solution is to loop trough a filtered list of project files:

```sh
    for proj in ./**/*Unit?Tests.*proj 
    do
      dotnet test "$proj" -c Release --no-build --filter "TestCategory!=SKIP_ON_DEPLOY & TestCategory!=REQUIRES_API_KEY"
    done
```

It's running the tests but differently from the cascade calls, here when a project test fails it does not fail the step so the pipeline does not stop!

I tried to get the result form the run, but unsuccessfully (this does not work):

```sh
    for proj in ./**/*Unit?Tests.*proj 
    do
      result=$(dotnet test "$proj" -c Release --no-build --filter "TestCategory!=SKIP_ON_DEPLOY & TestCategory!=REQUIRES_API_KEY")
      if result = 1
      then
        exit 1
      fi
    done
```

Any suggestion?
Why when `dotnet test` fails (exit 1) the step does not fail?
I tried to put in the loop only the failing test project and it fails in that case.

**[UPDATE]**
Full *pipeline.yaml*:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  project file: "Alex75.MySolution/Alex75.MyProject.fsproj"

steps:  

- script: dotnet build -c Release
  displayName: 'Build'
  
- script: |
    dotnet test "./ProjectTwo Unit Tests/ProjectTwo Unit Tests.fsproj" -c Release --no-build --filter "TestCategory!=SKIP_ON_DEPLOY & TestCategory!=REQUIRES_API_KEY"
    dotnet test "./ProjectOne Tests/ProjectOne Unit Tests.fsproj" -c Release --no-build --filter "TestCategory!=SKIP_ON_DEPLOY & TestCategory!=REQUIRES_API_KEY"
  displayName: 'Test'
  condition: false

- script: | 
    for proj in ./**/*Unit?Tests.*proj 
    do
      echo "run tests in $proj"
      dotnet test "$proj" -c Release --no-build --filter "TestCategory!=SKIP_ON_DEPLOY & TestCategory!=REQUIRES_API_KEY"
    done
  displayName: 'Test (Unit Test projects)'
  condition: true

- powershell: |
    $URL = "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/logs?api-version=5.1"
    Write-Host "URL = $URL"
  
    $logs = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $(PAT)"} -Method Get 
    $lastLogId = $Logs.value[$Logs.value.count-1].id
    Write-Host "lastLogId = $lastLogId"  
    $URL = "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/logs/$lastLogId?api-version=5.1"
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $(PAT)"} -Method Get 
    Write-Host $result

    Write-Host "Start Check result..."

    $lines = $result.Split([Environment]::NewLine)
    foreach($line in $lines) {
        if($line -match "Failed!")
        {
            throw 'dotnet test fails ($line)'
        }
    }

    Write-Host "Test result check completed."

  displayName: 'Check tests result'
```

### PowerShell script

Using the example of @vito-liu-msft I tried to check the test logs to check the error.

Here the powershell script alone:

```
$URL = "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/logs?api-version=5.1"
Write-Host "URL = $URL"
  
$logs = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $(PAT)"} -Method Get 
$lastLogId = $Logs.value[$Logs.value.count-1].id
Write-Host "lastLogId = $lastLogId"  

$URL = "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/logs/$lastLogId?api-version=5.1"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $(PAT)"} -Method Get 
Write-Host $result

Write-Host "Start Check result..."

$lines = $result.Split([Environment]::NewLine)
foreach($line in $lines) {
    if($line -match "Failed!")
    {
        throw 'dotnet test fails ($line)'
    }
}

Write-Host "Test result check completed."
```

**PAT**  is the Personal Access Token as it is created, no need to be transformed
before using it in the  HTTP request.
The **LogId** is not available so there is a request to get the *logs* collection and than a second request to get the specific last log (the response seems ordered by date, maybe it's worth to double check).

Note that if the second request returns a 404, 500 or other result (not a failure) the error check will not find a evenctual errors! A proper check of the response is required.

I tested the *-match "Failed!"* in PowerShell but I haven't tested the *throw* command in the pipeline because...

### *dotnet test* command in the loop is working!

After spending so much time trying to figure out how to read and check the logs throw a separate PowerShell script I find out that the initial simple solution works!
Yes, the build fails because of the test failure (it also shows the precise error pointing to the problem) and the step fails.
(so the next step, the check of the test results, is skipped!)

I think I should have made some error before on filtering the test projects so that the failing project was not running (and not raising any error) so I thoutght it was not "intercepting" the error, and the build didn't stop.
It could be that I mixed 2 different pipelines files while I was changing it.

Anyway this is the incriminated step (script):

```sh
    for proj in ./**/*Unit?Tests.*proj 
    do
      echo "run tests in $proj"
      dotnet test "$proj" -c Release --no-build --filter "TestCategory!=SKIP_ON_DEPLOY & TestCategory!=REQUIRES_API_KEY"
    done
```

At list with the *echo* it is possible to see which test projects are used.

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Honestly still looking to something simpler but definitely I'll have a look in couple of days. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when a project test fails it does not fail the step so the pipeline does not stop!
> Why when dotnet test fails (exit 1) the step does not fail?

As a workaround, we could get the `dotnet test` task log id via this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20logs?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1), add the task `power shell` and enter below script to analyze `dotnet test` log. we need to enter match code, such as `fails (exit 1)`, If dotnet test fails it will stop the pipeline.

We should add PAT to variable and set it to secret, then use it in the script

```
$connectionToken="{PAT}"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$URL = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs/{logId}?api-version=6.1-preview.2"
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get 
Write-Host $result
$lines = $result.Split([Environment]::NewLine)

        $passed = 0;
        $failed = 0;

        foreach($line in $lines) {
            if ($line -match "{match sentence}") { 
              throw 'dotnet test fails (exit 1)'

            }
        }
```

**Update1**

> how can I find the "logId" ?

We could use this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20logs?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to check logId

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs?api-version=6.1-preview.2
```

Result:

[image]

> And I really have to use a api "preview" version?

We could also use other version, such as 5.1, we could switch the REST API version in the doc, you could check the pic below.

[image]

Comment: I created a Personal Access Token and a Variable named "PAT" in the pipeline build.
Despite the documentation says:   
Batch script: %VARIABLE-NAME%  
PowerShell script: ${env:VARIABLE-NAME}     
Bash script: $(VARIABLE-NAME) actually to make it works in a PowerShell script I had to use $(VARIABLE NAME).  
Ok, I create the URL:
$URL = "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildNumber)/logs/{logId}?api-version=6.1-preview.2"  
Assuming "buildId" is correct, how can I find the "logId" ?
And I really have to use a api "preview" version?

Comment: Hi @Alex75, I have updated the answer, please check it.

Comment: Hi, Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if you have any questions. If the answer could help, you may consider accepting it. Thanks